# While using a web scraper how can I make sure that once the 1st page has been scraped it will then scrape the 2nd page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am looking to output the body of each review from the site. I am getting the correct output for the first page, but if there are 4 pages of reviews I get the text from the first page 4 times. How can I make sure that the scraper moves to the next page each time?

```
import lxml.html as html
import math
import csv
import requests
import re
import time

# Trustpilot review page
basePage = 'http://www.trustpilot.com/review/'
reviewSite = 'www.boo-hoo.com'
reviewPage = basePage + reviewSite

# Data file to save to
datafile = 'datascrap.csv'

# Trustpilot default
resultsPerPage = 20

print('Scraper set for ' + reviewPage + ' - saving result to ' + datafile)

# Get page, skipping HTTPS as it gives certificate errors
page = requests.get(reviewPage, verify=False)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# Total amount of ratings
ratingCount = tree.xpath('//h2[@class="header--inline"]')
ratingCount = ratingCount[0].text.replace(',','')
ratingCount = ratingCount.replace(u'\xa0', u'')
ratingCount = ratingCount.replace(u'\n', u'')
ratingCount = ratingCount.replace(u'Average', u'')
ratingCount = ratingCount.replace(u' ', '')
ratingCount = ratingCount.replace(u'•', '')
ratingCount = ratingCount.replace(u'Great', '')
ratingCount = int(ratingCount)

# Amount of chunks to consider for displaying processing output
# For ex. 10 means output progress for every 10th of the data
tot_chunks = 20

# Throttling to avoid spamming page with requests
# With sleepTime seconds between every page request
throttle = True
sleepTime = 2

# Total pages to scrape
pages = math.ceil(ratingCount / resultsPerPage)
print('Found total of ' + str(pages) + ' pages to scrape')

with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    # Tab delimited to allow for special characters
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    print('Processing..')
    for i in range(1, pages + 1):

        if (throttle): time.sleep(sleepTime)

        page = requests.get(reviewPage + '?page=' + str(i))
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

        # The item below scrapes a review body.
        bodies = tree.xpath('//p[@class="review-content__text"]')

        for idx, e in enumerate(bodies):
            # Progress counting, outputs for every processed chunk
            reviewNumber = idx + 20 * (i - 1) + 1
            chunk = int(ratingCount / tot_chunks)
            if reviewNumber % chunk == 0:
                print('Processed ' + str(reviewNumber) + '/' + str(ratingCount) + ' ratings')

            # Body of comment
            body = e.text_content().strip()
            datawriter.writerow([body])
    print('Processed ' + str(ratingCount) + '/' + str(ratingCount) + ' ratings.. Finished!')
```

If, for example, the site has 80 reviews I will get the first 20 four times but when I have tried printing the page each time through it shows it is going to 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: can you provide the full code?

Comment: Full code has been added. Thanks. @chitown88

Comment: if the solution worked out below, be sure to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reviewSite` was incorrect. change from `reviewSite = 'www.boo-hoo.com'` to `reviewSite = 'boo-hoo.com'`

if you go to page 2 in the browser, you'll see it as:

```
https://www.trustpilot.com/review/boo-hoo.com?page=2
```

but you're concatenating `www.boo-hoo.com`, so it's incorrectly trying to go to:

```
https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.boo-hoo.com?page=2
```

which then defaults to first page